# How do I take apart this LED magnifying glass?

Tags: office

It runs on two AA batteries and the switch is dirty so the LEDs flicker.   It has no identifying/manufacturer marks anywhere...including inside the battery compartment.  I'm loath to pry it apart lest I ruin it

[image]

Comment: if u r sure the flickering is due to the switch there's some chance (little) you can clean it either by an electric contact cleaning spray (if u have access to) or just by spaying rubbing alcohol from the switch gap and body, then switching on/off for a minute and letting it dry. Check the battery contacts also. IMHO if u c some screws then it would be way better to open it and have it throughly clean. what I would do (i don't recommend tho, only if I couldn't get in), a good spray in the battery cmpt and switch, a good shake, rinse, and waiting a few hours to dry.

Comment: Electric contact cleaner isn't always the right solution. I tried that on the car's window switches, and it caused some plastic parts to degrade and go brittle, and the switch broke after about a week.

Comment: Thanks, I had cleaned the battery contacts.   That didn't help.  I think I'll try dousing it with alcohol and operating the switch several times.  But there is no way of knowing if the alcohol will get to the contacts.   I do have contact cleaner and will use that as a last resort.     I would still feel better if I could open it up.

Comment: The usual solution for "cheap" items like this is to throw them away and buy another.  Fixing this with a little alcohol and a syringe is a good lifehack.  Nice job!

Comment: @ZeissIkon I was wondering if you meant *recycle* it until I came across [US produces far more waste and recycles far less of it than other developed countries](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/jul/02/us-plastic-waste-recycling).

Comment: @WeatherVane True.  Some places (like where I live) it's technically illegal to (for instance) throw plastic bottles into the landfill -- but there are no facilities for recycling them.  Most plastics can't actually be recycled in this country anyway (recycling pickup results in wasted time/money before they go to incineration), though some areas do a good job with glass, paper, and aluminum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed!** I got some alcohol (90 percent) and remembered I had a syringe. I was able to accurately squirt alcohol in the crevice between the switch and button when I depressed it. Works perfect now!